# Unable to remove duplicate values from XML, using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, soa

I have tried below Solution

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/esbMsg/rqData/customer" group-by="identityNumber">
         <xsl:sequence select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
```

But this not worked for me. As my XML has namespaces. I remove namespace above solution works fine. As i have requirement I need namespace to call next service.

I am trying to eliminate duplicate `<com:identityNumber>`.

```
<tns:esbMsg xmlns:leadapi="http://schemas.xyz.co.in/esb/api/sales/opportunity/v1"
            xmlns:comp="http://schemas.xyz.co.in/esb/eo/resilience/compliance/v1"
            xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xyz.co.in/esb/eo/misc/content/v1"
            xmlns:appo="http://schemas.xyz.co.in/esb/eo/communication/appointment/v1"
            xmlns:asset="http://schemas.xyz.co.in/esb/eo/accounts/asset/v1"
            xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xyz.co.in/esb/eo/sales/lead/v1"
            xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xyz.co.in/esb/eo/accounts/application/v1"
            xmlns:com="http://schemas.xyz.co.in/esb/eo/common/v1"
            xmlns:tns="http://schemas.xyz.co.in/esb/eo/parties/customer/v1">
   <tns:rqData>
      <tns:customer>
         <tns:id>22812</tns:id>
         <tns:cif/>
         <com:personName>
            <com:fullName>LEN 1301 Legal repre</com:fullName>
         </com:personName>
         <com:identityDoc>
            <com:identityType>IIC</com:identityType>
            <com:identityNumber>2017061119892016</com:identityNumber>
         </com:identityDoc>
         <tns:currentAddress>
            <com:addressLine1/>
         </tns:currentAddress>
         <com:trailer>
            <com:createdBy>rm</com:createdBy>
         </com:trailer>
      </tns:customer>
      <tns:customer>
         <tns:id>22813</tns:id>
         <tns:cif/>
            <tns:identityNumber>383983983983</tns:identityNumber>
         <com:personName>
            <com:fullName>LEN 1301 Capita Contributor </com:fullName>
         </com:personName>
         <com:identityDoc>
            <com:identityType>IIC</com:identityType>
            <com:identityNumber>383983983983</com:identityNumber>
         </com:identityDoc>
         <tns:currentAddress>
            <com:addressLine1/>
         </tns:currentAddress>
         <com:trailer>
            <com:createdBy>rm</com:createdBy>
         </com:trailer>
      </tns:customer>
      <tns:customer>
         <tns:id>22814</tns:id>
         <tns:cif/>
         <tns:identityNumber>2017061119892016</tns:identityNumber>
         <com:personName>
            <com:fullName>LEN 1301 Collateral</com:fullName>
         </com:personName>
         <com:identityDoc>
            <com:identityType>IIC</com:identityType>
            <com:identityNumber>2017061119892016</com:identityNumber>
         </com:identityDoc>
         <tns:currentAddress>
            <com:addressLine1/>
         </tns:currentAddress>
         <com:trailer>
            <com:createdBy>rm</com:createdBy>
         </com:trailer>
      </tns:customer>
      <tns:customer>
         <tns:id>20005</tns:id>
         <tns:cif/>
         <tns:identityNumber>2017061119892016</tns:identityNumber>
         <com:personName>
            <com:fullName>LEN 1301 main cust</com:fullName>
         </com:personName>
          <com:identityDoc>
            <com:identityType>IIC</com:identityType>
            <com:identityNumber>2017061119892016</com:identityNumber>
         </com:identityDoc>
         <tns:currentAddress>
            <com:addressLine1>hanoi</com:addressLine1>
         </tns:currentAddress>
         <com:trailer>
            <com:createdBy>rm</com:createdBy>
         </com:trailer>
      </tns:customer>
   </tns:rqData>
</tns:esbMsg>
```

Answer (score 1):

The elements in your source document are in various namespaces, which you have completely ignored in your path expressions. You need to use prefixed names in your path expressions, with the namespace prefix bound to the correct namespace.

Comment: I have used Prefix As well result was  blank.

 <xsl:for-each-group select="/*:esbMsg/*:rqData/*:customer" group-by="identityNumber">
         <xsl:sequence select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each-group>

Comment: @PrabhatSingh `identityNumber` is in a namespace too.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for pointers  It works for me

<tns:esbMsg>
      <tns:rqData>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/tns:esbMsg/tns:rqData/tns:customer" group-by="com:identityDoc/com:identityNumber">
          <xsl:sequence select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </tns:rqData>
    </tns:esbMsg>